# Magento 2 get customer attribute value issue

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes

I am trying to get customer attribute value i have created text attribute and storing json data.

```
{"cloud":["<div><span style=\"font-family:Comic Sans MS,cursive\"><u><span style=\"font-size:36px\"><strong>sfsdfsf<\/strong><\/span><\/u><\/span><\/div>\r\n",{"56":{"sku":"M816C","qty":"1","dosage_amount":"1-3","mesure":"tablets","dosage_frequency":"daily","dosage_options":"","remarks":""}}],"cloud1":["<div><span style=\"font-family:Comic Sans MS,cursive\"><u><span style=\"font-size:36px\"><strong>adad<\/strong><\/span><\/u><\/span><\/div>\r\n",{"110":{"sku":"M108","qty":"1","dosage_amount":"","mesure":"","dosage_frequency":" ","dosage_options":"","remarks":""}}]}
```

When i am getting data entire data not coming.
It coming like below:

> {"cloud1":["
>   adad</strong></span></u></span></div>\r\n",{"110":{"sku":"M108","qty":"1","dosage_amount":"","mesure":"","dosage_frequency":"
>   ","dosage_optiotest

Comment: can you please check in the database that there is all data in database

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?